How to sort by number in a text.combine field for multiple columns?
I have a generated report where I basically 'transpose' and combine two separate columns (Unpivot, Remove Duplicates, Pivot, Text.Combine, List.Sort).
I found this post, where it shows how to sort a single column.  However, I can't figure out how to numerically sort two separate columns.
Is this possible please?
Example of Raw report:

This is the result I'm trying to obtain:

This is the code I currently have. When I tried to add another line to sort the "Division #" Column, it would then unsort the "Warehouse Number" Column.
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Case GTIN Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Value", type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Duplicates", List.Distinct(#"Removed Duplicates"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value",each Text.Combine(_, ",")),
    #"Sort Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Pivoted Column",
    {"Warehouse Number", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(Text.Split(_,",")),",")})
in
    #"Sort Column"


Try
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Case GTIN Number"}, {
    {"Warehouse Number", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Distinct(_[Warehouse Number])),",")},
    {"Division #", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Distinct(_[#"Division #"])),",")}
})
in #"Grouped Rows"


